Unable to launch Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda - ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'
when launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda, I get the following Error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'


I've already tried uninstalling markupsafe and reinstalling it. I also tried pip3 install markupsafe==2.0.1, as suggested in the answers of this post
stackoverflow
I've also tried uninstalling, reinstalling and upgrading jupyter.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Try writing the following code in Anaconda Prompt:
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1 --force-reinstall


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
